# Solve $(2y^{2}+xy+y)dx-(3x^{2}+4yx+x)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $(2y^{2}+xy+y)dx-(3x^{2}+4yx+x)dy=0$

**My approach:** Since that $$P(x,y)=2y^{2}+xy+y \implies P_{y}(x,y)=4y+x+1$$
and $$Q(x,y)=-3x^{2}-4yx-x \implies Q_{x}(x,y)=-6x-4y-1$$
So, we can see that $P_{y}\not=Q_{x}$. So, the ODE is not exact equation.

Also, we can see that we cannot to rewrite the ODE as $f(x)dx=g(y)dy$, so the ODE is not separable equation. I think it's clear that the ODE is not Bernoulli's equation. Since that we don't have the form $y'=f(y/x)$ or $y'=f((a_{1}x+a_{2}y+a_{3})/(b_{0}x+b_{1}y+b_{3}))$ so we can't use the homogeneous method of solutions for the ODE.

---

How can I find a integrate factor for to solve this ODE-nonlinear or maybe a substitution?

Comment: Since you can factor $y$ from first term and $x$ from second term, it appears $(\cdots)\frac{dx}{x}+(\cdots)\frac{dy}y$, I tried substitution in $e^x,e^y$. This leads to simpler ODE, e.g. $(4e^y+3e^x+1)y' = 2e^y+e^x+1$ with no square or cross product. WA is able to integrate this, result is neither nice nor ugly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(2y^2+xy+y)dx-(3x^2+4yx+x)dy=0$$
Since one cannot find a simple form of integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ , we try some more complicated forms. For example
$$\mu(x,y)=x^py^q(y+cx)^r$$
$$\begin{cases}
N(x,y)=(2y^2+xy+y)x^py^q(y+cx)^r\\
M(x,y)=-(3x^2+4yx+x)x^py^q(y+cx)^r
\end{cases}$$
$$N(x,y)dx+M(x,y)dy=0$$
The condition to be an exact DE is :
$$\frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial x}$$
So we have to compute $\frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial x}$. After simplification of $\frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial x}$ we have a system of rather simple equations which solving leads to :
$$p=-2 \quad;\quad q=\frac12 \quad;\quad r=-\frac12 \quad;\quad c=1.$$
So, an integrating factor is
$$\boxed{\mu(x,y)=\frac{y^{1/2}}{x^2(x+y)^{1/2}}}$$
The exact DE is :
$$(2y+x+1)\frac{y^{3/2}}{x^2(x+y)^{1/2}}dx-(3x+4y+1)\frac{y^{1/2}}{x(x+y)^{1/2}}dy=0$$
Then one can integrate.

Comment: Nice solution :-) Thank you so much!